# PCRE REGEX Passing a variable

Tags: php, regex

I am new to PHP. 
How do I pass a `$Variable` into the Quantifier section of a REGEX in PHP.

```
$name = "JOHN";
$lname = "SMITH";
$str2l = strlen($lname);
$num = "04454318000007010100000SMITH JOHN";
$re = "/([0-9]+.$name\s+[.$lname]{4})/";
$q = preg_match($re, $num, $matches);
```

The above comes back `TRUE` and it matches, I want to pass the following `$variable` in the quantifier `{$str2l}`

Ex: `$re = "/([0-9]+.$name\s+[.$lname]{$str2l})/";`

How do I get this to work?? I don't get the right response, unless I type in a number.
I do NOT know the length of `.$lname` for the quantifier, unless I do String length.

Comment: I added Ex: $re = "/([0-9]+.$name\s+[.$lname]{.$str2l})/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a string interpolation issue. `"$var"` is the same as `"{$var}"` in PHPs double quoted strings. See the [curly variable syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) explanation.

You could either just double up on the `{}` curly braces:

```
$re = "/([0-9]+.$name\s+[.$lname]{{$str2l}})/";
```

Or patch the number in:

```
$re = "/([0-9]+.$name\s+[.$lname]{" . $str2l . "})/";
```

The first option may or may not look more confusing. But at least it's not a pointless concatenation.